# I have multiple private repos in github, how can I place dependency from one to another?

Tags: github, scala

I don't know if this is even valid, but here goes.

I have three repos in my private github:

1. Main project - Play App
2. Common - Sbt project containing shared code/classes/interfaces(mostly akka actors)
3. Impl - Sbt project containing implementations of certain interfaces in Common

The way the dependency works here is that **Main** is dependepent on **Impl**, **Impl** is dependent on **Common**

So **Common** will have some interfaces for **Impl** to implement. **Common** will also have some implementations of basic services.

**Impl** will implement some akka actor classes which **Main** will use to do its work.

How can I accomplish this in the build.sbt file?

Comment: Deploy jars to something like artifactory and add as build dependencies, or use submodules.

Comment: I wouldn't use submodules as there are quiet difficult to use from experience. A submodule must point on a specific commit of the parent repo, therefore if you want to sync your submodules with the parent, you need to move that "pointer" to the right commit (which ends like using an artifact repository).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather put all the code in the same repository, and use a artifact repository like bintree or (as mentioned by Daenyth) artifactory. Code versioning and dependency management are two separate things.

BTW, splitting your code across several repositories can get your release process much harder as new modules are added. You'd rather publish three different artifacts using a single version (just like Apache), and store the code in one place.